# In App Purchase Unique Identifying Data

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

O.K so I'm writing a iPhone travel guide, you purchase a subscription to a travel guide for 3 months, it downloads a fairly hefty database and for 3 months that database gets updated weekly with new stuff.

Now what I'd like to do is make the user enter their email address as a one off action before they purchase their first guide, for China say. The purpose for doing this is

1) To allow me to contact the user by email when they add a note/tip for a particular place (the app will allow them to send notes & information to me)

2) To Uniquely identify who has purchased the subscription so that if they wipe their device and reinstall the app they can plug the email address in and pickup their subscriptions again. Or so they can use the same subscription on another device they own.

My concerns are

1) Will Apple allow the email method of restoring functionality to a second or restored device?

2) As long as I tell the user what I'm using their email address for (aka I won't sell it to anyone else and use it for X purposes) will it be o.k to ask for said email address?

And as a side note, can I tack the devices unique id onto my server comms to track devices or is apple going to through a hissy fit about that as well?

Comment: To the side note. Apple encourages you to use the devices unique id to identify a given device.
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier

Comment: >> if they wipe their device and reinstall the app they can plug the email address in and pickup their subscriptions again

StoreKit does this for you. The API has a way to check for past purchases and the guidelines actually state you should offer this functionality. The user just enters their iTunes details and StoreKit does it all for you.

Comment: Unless this http://openradar.appspot.com/7470096 has been fixed? It seems to me you can't restore a users "subscriptions" based on their iTunes account. So I need some way of tracking users across multiple devices.

Answer (score 2):

Our app got rejected because we used email to uniquely identify the user. From apple review guidelines:

17.2   Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected

For subscriptions UDID can't be used to uniquely identify the user. So we were using email address. Back to drawing board.

Comment: Note that the Marvel Comic App requires an Account before letting user buy Comics. Isn't that the same?

Comment: Probably not. I released app that required custom account to function few weeks ago and they didn't have problem with it (they only required test account for testing). I don't see the difference, but seems like Apple does, it wouldn't be first time they let someone get away while stoping someone else who did very similar thing